# Computer Integral with Non-Equispaced Partitions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Just about to finish my analysis course, but I've having some trouble with a few problems for my final assignment.  Any help would be awesome as this course is driving me mad!  Thanks so much for the help.  You have no clue what a relief resources like this site are!

**Forward to the Problem:**

In the definition of the integral, we considered partitions of intervals to be arbitrary, but whenever we actually computed one, we used equispaced partitions. The following is a famous example of how to integrate $f(x) = x^t$ for any $t > 0$ directly using non-equispaced partitions. Let $a < b$ be positive numbers, and for any positive integer n, let $r = (b/a)^{1 \over n} > 1$. Then,

$a< ar^0< ar^1< ar^2 < ... < ar^{n-1}< ar^{n}=b$

so if we set $x_i = ar^i$ for $i = 0 ... n$, then $ P_n = \lbrace x_0,...,x_n \rbrace $ is a  is a partition of $[a, b]$.

**Part A:**

Super easy, no need for help here :)

I just had to show that $x^t$ was an increasing function.

**Part B:**

Using the formula for summing geometric series, show that $L(f, P_n) = a^{t+1}(r-1)(r^{n(t+1)}-1)=(b^{t+1}-a^{t+1})(r-1)/(r^{t+1}-1)$, and $U(f, P_n)=r^t(f,P_n)$

**Part C:** Use the last problem and part (b) to prove that:

$inf_{n\ge\ 1} U (f,P_n)=sup_{n\ge\ 1}=(b^{t+1}-a^{t+1})/(t+1)$

**The last problem:**

Let $a_n=\gamma^{s \over n}$ then for $\gamma, s > 0$ and all positive integers $n$:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$

Comment: Hint: write expressions for the lower and upper Darboux sums; express each of them as the difference of two geometric progressions.

Comment: Still super confused!  So far I have: $S_t=\sum_i=1^k m_i \delta x_i$ with $x_i=ar^i$.  So $$L(f,P_n)=\sum_i=1^k m_i \Delta x_i=a*\sum_i=1^k (x_i-x_{i-1}=a \left {1-r^{k+1}\over {1-r}-{1-r^{k}\over {1-r} \right $$  This is clearly not what I'm looking for!  Any extra help?  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Fermat described this method well before Newton was born.

Comment: @Yuri Still super confused!  So far I have: $S_t=\sum_i=1^k m_i \delta x_i$ with $x_i=ar^i$.  So $$L(f,P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^k m_i \Delta x_i=a*\sum_{i=1}^k x_i-x_{i-1}=a \left( {1-r^{k+1} \over {1-r}}-{1-r^k \over 1-r} \right)$$    This is clearly not what I'm looking for!  Any extra help?  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. What is the value of $m_i$? $m_i$ is not equal to $a$; it depends on $i$. Also your summation limits are incorrect. What is $k$?

Comment: @Yury $m_i= inf \{ f(x): x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \}$, with that in mind, should it actually be:  $$L(f,P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^k m_i \Delta x_i=\sum_{i=1}^k m_ia_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$  Sorry for the silly question!  I'm really confused!

Comment: What is $a_i$? The function $f(x)$ is monotone; so there is an explicit formula for $m_i$. What point does $f(x)$ attains its minimum at on the segment $[x_{i-1},x_i]$?

Comment: Please don't blank questions. If you found the answer, you could write it up for posterity. If you don't want to invest the time, you could just delete the question.